# Sort a list according to the ascending sort of the second list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two unsorted lists, x and y, as follows:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
y = [ 5,   1,   4,   2,   3]
```

I would like to sort list y two times, one in ascending order and then in descending order. But, in each sorting of y, I need to sort also the corresponding elements of the list x accordingly.
Both lists have the same length of items.

I tried with the following code, but it is not working as expected:

```
def sort_list(list1, list2): 

    zipped_pairs = zip(list2, list1) 

    z = [x for _, x in sorted(zipped_pairs)] 
  
    return z 

print(sort_list(x, y))
```

**Expected output: in case of ascending order**

```
x = [ "b", "d","e", "c", "a"] 
y = [  1,   2, 3, 4,  5]
```

Any help?

Comment: That *does* give `['b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a']`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want to `return` both sorted lists instead of only the first one?

Comment: Yes. I need to return both sorted list, as explained in the question.

Comment: But you already know what the sorted version of `y` will be - that's the point, that's why you're using it to sort `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just zip `y` and `x` - in this order, so that you can sort the resulting tuples in natural order, by their first item.

You can then sort, and zip again:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
y = [ 5,   1,   4,   2,   3] 

sorted_y, sorted_x = zip(*sorted(zip(y, x)))

print(sorted_x, sorted_y)
#('b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a') (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In reverse order:

```
sorted_y, sorted_x = zip(*sorted(zip(y, x), reverse=True))
print(sorted_x, sorted_y)
# ('a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'b') (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: ... and this is twice as fast as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. This answer is correct and fast!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using the `key` parameter in `sorted`, keeping much of your same code:

```
def sort_list(list1, list2):
    zip_pairs=zip(list2, list1)
    z = sorted(zip_pairs, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return z

x, y = zip(*sort_list(x,y))
print(x,y)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ('b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
y = [ 5,   1,   4,   2,   3]

def sort_list(list1, list2):
    indexs = {k: v for (k, v) in zip(list2, list1)}
    list2 = sorted(list2)
    list1 = [indexs[i] for i in list2]
    return (list1, list2)

sort_list(x, y)
>>> (['b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by combining both the arrays and then sorting the entire based on second column of the array. Suppose the array is as follows:

```
arr = [['a',5],['b',1],['c',4],['d',2],['e',3]]
```

Now, sort the `arr` variable using the 2nd columns as follows:

```
arr.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
```

Output

```
[['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 3], ['c', 4], ['a', 5]]
```

Now, access the first elements of the array

Answer (score 0):

This function works, I also added the invert order variable:

```
import numpy as np


def sort_list(list1, list2, invert = False): 

    sorted_idex = np.argsort(list2)
    if invert:
        return list1[sorted_idex[::-1]], list2[sorted_idex[::-1]]
    else:
        return list1[sorted_idex], list2[sorted_idex]


x = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
y = np.array([ 5,   1,   4,   2,   3])

print(sort_list(x, y)) 
print(sort_list(x, y, invert=True))
```

giving the results:

```
(array(['b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a'], dtype='<U1'), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
(array(['a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'b'], dtype='<U1'), array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: `nx[ny.argsort()]` where `nx=np.array(x)` and `ny=np.array(y)`

Answer (score 0):

x and y are the two default parameters assuming them to be in List. The solution is without using zip.

```
    x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
    y = [ 5,   1,   4,   2,   3]
    X, Y = [], sorted(y)
    for i in Y:
        X.append(x[y.index(i)])
    x,y = X,Y 
    print(x)
    print(y)
```